# "Tanti/tante" = many or so many?

Tags: word-meaning

I have seen "tanti/tante" translated as "many" and "so many". How can I decide when they mean the former or the latter? Examples:

- Ci sono tanti temporali. (= There are so many thunderstorms)
- In estate ci sono tanti temporali. (= There are many thunderstorms in (the) summer)
- Come mai tante mosche in questa stanza? ( = How come there are so many flies in this room? )

The question arose when I translated "tanti" as "so many" in the second sentence and a native Italian speaker told me "tanti" was closer to "many" in that sentence.

Comment: Mmmm... I've always find very difficult trying to learn the meaning of a word in a language in terms of translations to another language.

Comment: @Charo Agreed. if you could first explain the meaning of tanti/tante and then say why it sometimes translates as "many" and sometimes as "so many", even better. Reading Treccani's definition, I could not understand it.

Comment: “Reading Treccani's definition, I could not understand it”: What did you not understand? A complete answer should in fact be some of a paraphrase of that entry...

Comment: @DaG "Al plur. (o al sing. collettivo), di cose, di persone e di animali, così numeroso, in così gran numero" = "In the plural (or in the collective singular), used with things, people and animals, so numerous, in such a big quantity" . Please correct me if I have made some mistake in the translation. "*so* numerous" and "*such* a big quantity" imply emphasis to me and that's the exact meaning I see in "so many", so I do not understand why how it can mean just "many".

Comment: «Tanto» si usa spesso come «molto», sia nel senso di aggettivo che di pronome; prende un significato enfasi nei casi in cui c’è «così», sottinteso o meno. Dei tre esempi proposti, il primo e il secondo sono di fatto uguali: forse le frasi hanno poi una continuazione?

Comment: Your translation is perfect. “Tanto/i” implies emphasis and often a comparison. But it is often used as just “much/many” (as you also see in Treccani 1.f).

Comment: I agree with @Benedetta: why are you distinguishing between your first two examples? Without a context, there is no way of knowing whether the utterer meant “many”, “so many”, “as many as [something else]”...

Comment: @Benedetta Come sai quando "così" è sottinteso ?

Comment: @DaG The first sentence is probably bad translated then, I got it from Google Translate. We may disconsider it. Anyway, my problem is that I am unable to infer when "tanto/tanta/tanti/tante has an implied emphasis (= così). If I understood you right, there is no rule and it must me learned case by case.

Comment: Not quite, Alan: it must not be learnt case by case, but _understood_ case by case. The first sentence may well mean both things and other ones too, as I mentioned. Not knowing what is being said before and after, however, we cannot decide which. Consider this: in the sentence “it is red”, does “it” refer to a chair?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Si capisce da quello che si dice prima o dopo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic meaning of *tanto/tanti* is “in such a large quantity”.

In the simplest case this may simply conclude an explicit comparison. Take the famous lines by Dante:

> dietro le venìa sì lunga tratta
>   di gente, ch'i' non averei creduto
>   che morte tanta n'avesse disfatta

In Dorothy L. Sayers's translation, this is “...there the folk forlorn / Rushed after it [a moving ensign], in such an endless train, / It never would have entered in my head / There were so many men whom death had slain”. So here *tanta* (feminine as it refers to *gente*) is rendered as “so many.” (This is alluded to in T.S. Eliot's *The Waste Land*: “A crowd flowed over London Bridge, so many, / I had not thought death had undone so many.”)

It is not necessary to make the comparison term explicit. If you said:

> Non credevo che d'estate ci fossero tanti temporali.

you'd be implicitly saying “...as many as there actually are” or simply “so many”. To take one of the examples from [Treccani's entry on *tanto*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tanto):

> ci vuole tanto tempo per rispondere?

(“do you need such a long time to answer?”, more or less), here you are precisely referring to, say, the five minutes your interlocutor waited before answering.

Notice that in all of these examples, if you used *molto/molti*, either the sentence wouldn't work or the meaning would change. You cannot use *molto* in a correlation (Dante's sentence or one with an analogous structure wouldn't mean anything with *molta*). If you asked

> ci vuole molto tempo per rispondere?

you'd just be asking whether an answer is due in a long time or not.

In common use, it's frequent to find *tanto* as almost a synonym for *molto*, but even then there is often a sense of correlation with something unexpressed or, at least, a particular emphasis. If I say

> Ho tanta voglia di vederti

I'm saying “I have such a desire to see you”, as if implying that I can't stand it any more (“tanta voglia ... che verrei lì stanotte”, say). On the other hand “ho molta voglia di vederti” is just that my desire is, say, 8 in a 1-10 scale.

You may well find cases where *tanto* is used as a plain *molto*: complex or hyperbolic words and expressions are often attenuated through use.

Just think about *troppo*: its meaning is *too much* or *too [adjective/adverb]*. So, if I say that a thing is *troppo bella*, literally I'd be saying that it is “too beautiful” (so, for instance, we should find a less beautiful one for a particular use). But is it usual to hear this as a positive description, as if it meant that that thing is exceptionally beautiful.

Comment: this has indeed helped. Thank you for the effort.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, in short, tanto/tanta/tanti/tante has an implied "così" and mean "so much/many" when the sentence expresses a comparison. I do not mean to be rude, but I'd like to make a constructive criticism: IMHO your answer would me more didactic and much easier to understand with a simpler example instead of the literary example from Dante.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @AlanEvangelista. I do not mean to be rude either, but I'd like to make a constructive criticism: IMHO your learning would proceed less haphazardly and much quicker if you abandoned your “learning tools”, which prove daily to be ridden of mistakes and unidiomatic--or plain wrong--examples and started appreciating actual Italian texts (not necessarily Dante).

Comment: Could you provide an example (with context) when "tanti"/"tante" would not contain an implicit/explicit comparison and therefore should be translated as "many" to English? I cannot find one in http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tanto/

Answer (score 1):

The translation on the first example is wrong because "così" is not implied at all.
The correct Italian translation for "There are so many thunderstorms" is: "Ci sono così tanti temporali".

On the third example instead the translation is correct although shortened and the "così" is implied.
The full sentence would be: "Ci sono così tante mosche in questa stanza".

Comment: Welcome to Italian SE!

Comment: Matteo, are you aware of the fact that the basic meaning of _tanto_ is precisely “così grande, in così gran quantità, e con sign. più determinati, così lungo, così ampio, così esteso, così forte, così intenso, ecc.”? (See [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tanto), quoted, or any other dictionary). It may _also_ simply mean “molto/i”, but as a secondary meaning. Don't worry, however, it's a misconception common to some Italians too.

Comment: @DaG is it really secondary though? I feel that in quite a lot of those sentences one could without second thoughts substitute "tanto" with "molto".

Comment: @Easymode44: Right, but the meaning would sometimes slightly change (there are basically no synonyms in human languages). “Ci sono molti temporali” is more factual, while “Ci sono tanti temporali” suggests, even in a stand-alone sentence, an implicit comparison (more than last year, I didn't expect so many and so on). It's one of the many precious little things of Italian. (In any case, I only meant “secondary” in a historical, etymological sense; I wouldn't know about the relative prevalences of the two meanings. Studying this could be interesting.)

Comment: @DaG interesting. Might be a generational thing, but I would personally not know how to distinguish between "tanti" and "molti" in your example. Also, every source that tries to lay out the difference clearly tends to be a bit blurry, IMHO. Also, is the logical consequence of all this that "così tanti" is generally wrong?

Comment: @Easymode44: I wouldn't call it wrong. It's often not necessary (“ho tante di quelle cose da dirti che non so da dove cominciare”), but you might use it for emphasis (“ho così tante...”). Just consider traditional proverbs (“Tanto va la gatta al lardo che ci lascia lo zampino”) or classical quotes (“dietro le venìa sì lunga tratta / di gente, ch'i' non averei creduto / che morte tanta n'avesse disfatta”): the main use is “so much/many”, with some comparison or correlation.

Comment: @DaG I see your point, and thanks for having pointed it out, but I am not 100% convinced. I guess having used them pretty much as synonyms my entire life makes it hard to digest. I would be curious to know what the other's perception on the matter is.

Comment: @Easymode44: I hope I have clarified the matter a bit in my answer.